# Load images during page startup

Tags: javascript

I am currently working with radio buttons and check boxes to display images based on values. I am noticing that the images are loading slowly at the start. For example, Have pre-created the image elements with "display:none" (with their src attribute already set) so then the only thing I have to do is play with the display attribute. Is there away to preload the images? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/bike_calculator/)

**JS**

```
<script>
function check_value(currentElement, val, id, type) {
    var el = document.getElementById("imgBox" + id);
    if (val > 0 && val < 4) { //will trigger when [1,2,3]

        if(currentElement.checked)
        {
            el.src = "images/" + type + val + ".jpg";
            el.style.display = "";
        }
        else
        {
            el.src = "";
            el.style.display = "none";
        }       

    }
}    
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Choose a bike</h2>
<form name="builder">
    <input type="radio" name="field" onclick='check_value(this, 1, 1, "bike")'/> KAWASAKI KX 450F<br />
    <input type="radio" name="field" onclick='check_value(this, 2, 1, "bike")'/> 2010 Yamaha Road Star S<br />
    <input type="radio" name="field" onclick='check_value(this, 3, 1, "bike")'/> Aprilia RSV4<br />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Preloading images is really easy if you have JQuery:

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}

$(['some-image.gif']).preload();
```

Also check this resource: http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Comment: Apparently it's considered bad S.O form to post JQuery-based answers to questions tagged `JavaScript`. Also, isn't the selector for an Img tag `$('img')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I've made for myself some time ago: http://pastebin.com/GeBawE8r

You can use it as follows:

```
var loader = new imagePreloader();

// Object containing the names of the imgs as keys and url as values
loader.list = {name: "url"...};

// function to call when done loading everything
loader.onload = ... 

// function to call at each time it loades a single image of the list
loader.each = ... 

// function to call when unable to load one of the images 
loader.onerror = ... 

// set this to true to continue even if some of the images fail to load 
loader.ignoreErrors = true/false

// Starts loading the images
loader.load();
```

After it's done loading the property `ready` will be set to true and you can access the images in the `list` object.

```
if(loader.ready)
    alert(loader.list.myImageName); // Image object
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uttZw/1